# Why does this sort function shift the sorted data upward?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table in the range B2:E9. I'm trying to sort only columns B and C. The sorting works, but the sorted cells are shifted up from row 2 to row 1.

I've searched for the last two hours for an answer. Can someone help me?

I think Excel may be having trouble recognizing my header because it starts on row 2 and row 1 is blank.

```
Columns("B:C").Sort Key1:=Range("C3:C9"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
```

Comment: You're sorting the entire column. I believe you instead want: `Range("B2:C9").Sort ...`

Comment: `Range("B2:C9").Sort` with `Header:=xlYes` or `Range("B3:C9").Sort` with `Header:=xlNo`

Comment: @jeeped Thank you! That worked!

Comment: @brucewayne Thank you!